# How to apply conditional styling to HTML Email Template file before sending with PHPMailer?

Tags: javascript, html, email, phpmailer

I would like to apply inline styling to an HTML Table template before sending the HTML file via PHPMailer. The mail function works correctly, and hard-coding stylistic attributes shows in the email. However I need to be able to conditionally apply styles to td's based on their value.

Which piece of this process can I add a script that manipulates the HTML file before its sent in the email? I've tried inserting the function into the html template file and attaching an event listener to the body of the template file, but this function needs to run before PHPMailer inserts it into the email body and capture the changes.

## email_template.html

```
 <body id="LManager" onload="myFunction()">
  <table id="LMtable">
    <thead>
      <th>License/Software Name</th>
       <th>Host (DNS)</th>
       <th>Host (IP)</th>
       <th>Current Duration</th>
       <th>Time remaining</th>
       <th>Expiration Date</th>
     </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Example</td>
              <td>Example.com</td>
              <td>10.0.0.0</td>
              <td>2 years</td>
              <td>185 days</td>
              <td>05/12/2018</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("LMtable").rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor  = "red";
            }
  </script>
```

## mailTest.php

```
  <?php

  require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'DNS,IP';
  $mail->Username = 'User';
  $mail->Password = 'P/W';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Port = 25;

  $mail->setFrom('Example@example.com', 'Ex');
  $mail->addAddress('group@example.com');

  $mail->isHTML(true);

  $mail->Subject = 'subject';
  $mail->Body = file_get_contents('/email_templates/email_template.html');



  if(!$mail->send()){
  echo 'error';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }else{
      echo 'Success!';
  }
  ?>
```

## mail_test.html

```
  <html>
   <body>
    <form action="mailTest.php" method="get" onsubmit="myFunction();" >
      <input type="submit" value="Run">
           </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load HTML pages in PHP (e.g. via `file_get_contents`), it doesn't run javascript, nor does JS work in email, so the JS in your template will never be run, and never do anything.

You need to reimplement the dynamic styling in PHP, either by inserting a style tag and classes into your template or inline styles.

A very simple dynamic PHP style based on your example:

```
<table id="LMtable">
    <thead>
      <th>License/Software Name</th>
       <th>Host (DNS)</th>
       <th>Host (IP)</th>
       <th>Current Duration</th>
       <th>Time remaining</th>
       <th>Expiration Date</th>
     </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td<?php if ($stylefirst): ?> style="background-color: red;"<?php endif; ?>>Example</td>
              <td>Example.com</td>
              <td>10.0.0.0</td>
              <td>2 years</td>
              <td>185 days</td>
              <td>05/12/2018</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

To actually get the output of this when it's run as a PHP script, you need to use `include`, not `file_get_contents`:

```
$mail->Body = include '/email_templates/email_template.php';
```

If you need to do this kind of thing with more complicated dynamic features, you may be better off using a templating language like Smarty or Twig.

Finally, you need to all this kind of processing *before* you pass the finished HTML to PHPMailer.